# What's the difference between `echo x > y` and `echo x | tee y`?

Tags: bash, shell

When I want to redirect output to a file, I usually do this:

```
$ echo 'a' > b
$ cat b
a
```

However, I've seen people use `tee` instead of redirecting directly to a file. I'm wondering what the difference is. What I mean in this pattern:

```
$ echo 'a' | tee c
a
$ cat c
a
```

It doesn't seem to be doing anything differently than a simple redirect. I know they are conceptually not the same thing, but I'm wondering why people would use one over the other.

Comment: Isn't the difference obvious? In the second case you see the output. And rather than just have it show up on the screen you can pipe it to other things. That said, it's probably a matter of personal habit.

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Yes, I've seen both, but I missed the obvious difference between the two patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tee` let's you split the output.  You can either view it (by directing stdout to the tty you are looking at) or pass it on to further processing.  It is handy for keeping track of intermediate stages of a pipeline.

Comment: Another benefit: you can do `echo a | sudo tee protected-file`, meaning you don't need to elevate the privileges for the first command.

Comment: @cbuckley Thanks for the tip. I think it was used in that sense when I saw it.

Answer (score 5):

In simple word

echo 'a' > b , it will write "a" to file b.

```
#echo 'a' > b
#cat b
#a
```

echo 'a' | tee b , it will write "a" to file b and will display output(echo output) in the terminal.

```
#echo 'a' | tee b
#a
#cat b
#a
```